# Экспорт строк MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Доброго времени суток, может кто может помочь - есть таблица, из нее запросом выбираю данные, выходит около 100 строк, можно ли эти 100 строк экспортировать в sql файл в MySQL Workbench?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выполняете запрос `SELECT * FROM db.table LIMIT 100`

После запроса надо нажать `Export recordset to an external file`:

[image]
Затем тип файла нужно выбрать `SQL INSERT statements (*.sql)`:

[image]

В файл `*.sql` сохранятся только записи из выборки (в примере 100).

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо. Сразу и не додумаешься)